# jQuery DatePicker restrict dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to restrict `jquery datepicker` values. So the the `from date` can not exceed the `to date` and vice versa.

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/21594/

I've tried multiple instances of this but can not seem to get it to work. Is it because I am using the UK date format?

```
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });

    $('#from_date').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateStr) {
            var min = $(this).datepicker('getDate') || new Date(); // Selected date or today if none
            var max = new Date(min.getTime());
            max.setMonth(max.getDay() + 1); // Add one month
            $('#to_date').datepicker('option', {minDate: min, maxDate: max});
        }
    });
    $('#to_date').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateStr) {
            var max = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); // Selected date or null if none
            $('#from_date').datepicker('option', {maxDate: max});
        }
    });
```

As i'm new to JavaScript i'm keen to know exactly why my code doesn't work, so i can learn from this.

Comment: Please Try https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/21595/

Comment: what you want to do is given as an example in the api documents https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Answer (score 1):

You cannot initialize date picker on same element twice. First, you called the date picker on element with its class; then with its ID.

Try to move the date format to date picker default function.

```
  $.datepicker.setDefaults({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        });
```

Or, you need to set dateFormat every time you initialize a date picker element.